# C++ Template method return ref to private map value where value's type is parent of T

Tags: c++, templates, casting, reference, unreal-engine4

I have a problem blowing my mind actually, and a challenge for someone, could you help me with that ? :

```cpp
class UItemEntity : public UObject
{
  GENERATE_BODY()

  public:
    template<typename T=FItemComponent>
    T& GetComponent()
    {
        auto Result = Components[TYPE_ID(T)];

        T Comp = reinterpret_cast<T>(Result);

        return Comp;
    }

  private:
    /** Map from Component's type ID to one of their instance associated to this entity. */
    TMap<const char*, FItemComponent> Components;
}
```

(It's Unreal c++ code but still c++ :P)

Example of usage :

```cpp
struct FTestComponent : public FItemComponent { }

UItemEntity* Item;
FTestComponent& Comp = Item->GetComponent<FTestComponent>();
```

I cannot figure out how to cast the value retrieved from the map... I tried static, dynamic and reinterpret cast but none succeeded.

Here is the kind of error I have :

`ItemEntity.h: [C2440] 'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'ValueType' to 'T'`

It might be an architecture problem, but I don't know how to work around :/ And I really need a GetComponent on this ItemEntity.

Thanks !

EDIT :

With the help of @Frank, I finally succeed in, there was some Unreal stuff to take into account.

Here it is :

```
class UItemEntity : public UObject
{
  GENERATE_BODY()

  public:
    template<typename T=FItemComponent>
    T& GetComponent()
    {
        const bool IsItemComponentType = std::is_base_of_v<FItemComponent, T>;
        check(IsItemComponentType);

        FItemComponent* ItemComp = *Components.Find(TYPE_ID(T));

        return Cast<T>(ItemComp);
    }

  private:
    /** Map from Component's type ID to one of their instance associated to this entity. */
    TMap<const char*, FItemComponent*> Components;
}
```

Comment: You can't return a references to a local variable. Also, the objects stored in the `Components` map are `FItemComponent` objects, all possible inheritance is lost and sliced away when storing the object in the map. You need to store *pointers* instead (snd keep the original objects alive).

Comment: For more information: [Object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), [What is object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) . `UItemEntity` object doesn't have an instance of `FTestComponent` to give out, by pointer, reference or otherwise.

Comment: Yep my bad, I edited it quicker while waiting some answers ^^ Thanks to pointed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some Unreal-specific shenanigans at play that I'm not aware of, but in general-purpose C++ code, it would look like this:

```
class UItemEntity : public UObject
{
  GENERATE_BODY()

  public:
    template<typename T>
    T& GetComponent()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<FItemComponent, T>);

        return *static_cast<T*>(Components.at(TYPE_ID(T)).get());
    }

  private:
    /** Map from Component's type ID to one of their instance associated to this entity. */
    TMap<const char*, std::unique_ptr<FItemComponent>> Components;
}
```

Explanation:

- Elements are stored as pointers since different types can be stored in it.
- `at()` is used because there is nothing the function can return if the entry is missing.
- `static_cast<>` lets the compiler known that the casting from base to derived is intentional.
- The pointer is dereferenced into a reference with `*`.
- I replaced the default template parameter with a `static_assert()`, according to the discussion in the comments.

You *may* want to use `std::shared_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr`, `std::reference_wrapper` or even a raw pointer instead of `std::unique_ptr` depending on the circumstances. However, it's hard to tell which is the correct one without some more context, so I used the baseline `unique_ptr` for this example.

Comment: `return *Components.at(TYPE_ID(T))` probably wouldn't compile, as it attempts to implicitly convert a base class lvalue to a presumed derived class reference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, good catch.

Comment: @Frank Thanks a lot for your answer ! Indeed, I completely miss the Map Value type and did not put a pointer... Blaming myself right now, haha. 
I don't quite get it why you did remove the template parameter ? As I want to be sure the type of the template is a child of a FItemComponent, and not a random type ;)

Comment: @FlipperDev That's not what the default template parameter does. The template can still accept anything, it's just the value used if none is specified. I'll amend the answer with how to perform that check.

Comment: Oops my bad, I'm coming from C# and I did not check the template doc with thoroughness ! RTFM.. 
Also, I understood your explanation and thanks for this details, but it does not work either, still the same error. It might comes from the TMap class from Unreal somehow..

Comment: @FlipperDev That's probably my bad, I should have added a `.get()` when I added the `static_cast`. Should be fixed now.

Comment: No that's not the fault of the unique_ptr, I'm using a raw pointer. Here is what the compiler is telling me : 
`ItemEntity.h(134): [C2440] Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`

Comment: So using `reinterpret_cast` is working well (at least compiling) but I'm not sure it's the right cast here..